# How to map JSON with array object to Model in SwiftUI? `Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call`

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, alamofire

I am new to SwiftUI and have been stuck for days in trying to map my backend API's JSON object into the SwitchUI Model (Which I think is the right way to approach this type of problem?). I am getting error while trying to initalize the variable.

I am trying to use Alamofire to get the response from my API in JSON and map that to a Published variable so I can print the list of businesses as the result.
The following is what I have and the I'm getting the
"Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call" error
on the line: @Published var result: Result = Result()

If I make the "[Businesses] and region" in my model as Optional, then I can't see them in the view. What is wrong here?
Thanks very much

View

```
class SearchFormModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var result: Result = Result()
```

```
        AF.request(backendApiURL, parameters: parameters).responseDecodable(of: Result.self) { response in
            debugPrint("Response:\(response)")
            
            switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):
                self.result = value
                print(value)
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
```

Model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

struct Result: Codable {
    var businesses : [Businesses]
    var region : Region
}

struct Businesses: Codable {
    var id : String = ""
    var alias : String?
    var name : String?
    var image_url : URL?
    var is_closed : Bool?
    var url : URL?
    var review_count : Int?
    var categories : [Categories]?
    var rating : Double?
    var coordinates : Coordinates?
    var transactions : [String]?
    var price : String?
    var location : Location?
    var phone : String?
    var display_phone : String?
    var distance : Double?
}

struct Categories: Codable {
    var alias : String = ""
    var title : String = ""
}

struct Coordinates: Codable {
    var latitude : Double = 0.0
    var longitude : Double = 0.0
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var address1 : String?
    var address2 : String?
    var address3 : String?
    var city : String?
    var zip_code : String?
    var country : String?
    var state : String?
    var display_address : [String]?
}

struct Region: Codable {
    var center : Center
}

struct Center : Codable {
    var longitude : Double = 0.0
    var latitude : Double = 0.0
}
```

Sample JSON

```
{
  "businesses": [
    {
      "id": "aDa5FQZdCghy3XwK_h93Fw",
      "alias": "worlds-best-pizza-hacienda-heights",
      "name": "World's Best Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ZPKyEBB5As3dVberckNyxg/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/worlds-best-pizza-hacienda-heights?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 409,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9801206981514,
        "longitude": -117.974323744633
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "3142 Colima Rd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Hacienda Heights",
        "zip_code": "91745",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "3142 Colima Rd",
          "Hacienda Heights, CA 91745"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16269684794",
      "display_phone": "(626) 968-4794",
      "distance": 2271.295381028884
    },
    {
      "id": "ovq2Sfpw7cQZbSMIqs07vg",
      "alias": "hacienda-heights-pizza-company-hacienda-heights",
      "name": "Hacienda Heights Pizza Company",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/codEYU-DR_GdRd7dsNsWyA/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/hacienda-heights-pizza-company-hacienda-heights?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 437,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 3.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.015013,
        "longitude": -117.973866
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "15239 Gale Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Hacienda Heights",
        "zip_code": "91745",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "15239 Gale Ave",
          "Hacienda Heights, CA 91745"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16268552590",
      "display_phone": "(626) 855-2590",
      "distance": 1980.1106887021883
    },
    {
      "id": "I92UQKaJKq9iaa4HTz2tXg",
      "alias": "scardinos-pizza-to-go-la-puente",
      "name": "Scardino's Pizza To Go",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/wE2Jm3DK-4bO_11xsXxGEQ/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/scardinos-pizza-to-go-la-puente?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 339,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "italian",
          "title": "Italian"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.0496506030785,
        "longitude": -117.946955922661
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "1627 N Hacienda Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "La Puente",
        "zip_code": "91744",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "1627 N Hacienda Blvd",
          "La Puente, CA 91744"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16269181507",
      "display_phone": "(626) 918-1507",
      "distance": 6552.790234543938
    },
    {
      "id": "XzW26Or2ITIbkoTh2XME4w",
      "alias": "fuoco-pizzeria-napoletana-fullerton",
      "name": "Fuoco Pizzeria Napoletana",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/wE95ltg-16GPwYJf4Aof0w/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/fuoco-pizzeria-napoletana-fullerton?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 1783,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "italian",
          "title": "Italian"
        },
        {
          "alias": "salad",
          "title": "Salad"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.87060085641833,
        "longitude": -117.92457732489875
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "101 N Harbor Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Fullerton",
        "zip_code": "92832",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "101 N Harbor Blvd",
          "Fullerton, CA 92832"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+17146260727",
      "display_phone": "(714) 626-0727",
      "distance": 15285.200290883491
    },
    {
      "id": "hTf8c43zQ7TFq6PHQAI2bw",
      "alias": "love-letter-pizza-and-chicken-rowland-heights",
      "name": "Love Letter Pizza & Chicken",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/zPQEFl8tgsXomodGvgvPMQ/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/love-letter-pizza-and-chicken-rowland-heights?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 990,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "korean",
          "title": "Korean"
        },
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "chicken_wings",
          "title": "Chicken Wings"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.989243,
        "longitude": -117.904673
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "18333B Colima Rd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Rowland Heights",
        "zip_code": "91748",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "18333B Colima Rd",
          "Rowland Heights, CA 91748"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16268391235",
      "display_phone": "(626) 839-1235",
      "distance": 7344.37662932068
    },
    {
      "id": "-5GSm4vuDDdtMaEPjPKwcQ",
      "alias": "vinnys-italian-restaurant-la-habra-2",
      "name": "Vinny's Italian Restaurant",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/x7mpbYWdKfoY465wY41wsQ/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/vinnys-italian-restaurant-la-habra-2?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 1090,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "italian",
          "title": "Italian"
        },
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.92514,
        "longitude": -117.92276
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "2101 E Lambert Rd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "La Habra",
        "zip_code": "90631",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "2101 E Lambert Rd",
          "La Habra, CA 90631"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15626943400",
      "display_phone": "(562) 694-3400",
      "distance": 9950.263973452404
    },
    {
      "id": "_FuGSE3AYx9nOTkODPut1g",
      "alias": "la-crosta-wood-fired-pizza-whittier",
      "name": "La Crosta Wood Fired Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/vdBfsfjDqDnxap0BwSLtdQ/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-crosta-wood-fired-pizza-whittier?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 59,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9787781,
        "longitude": -118.0370427
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "location": {
        "address1": "13002 Philadelphia St",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": null,
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90601",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "13002 Philadelphia St",
          "Whittier, CA 90601"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15623247577",
      "display_phone": "(562) 324-7577",
      "distance": 5430.611951758044
    },
    {
      "id": "5bjEj57xtVg59fsIjWGCzQ",
      "alias": "blackjack-pizzeria-la-habra",
      "name": "Blackjack Pizzeria",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/5uQoPZ5RDa_uFS8tnioUSg/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/blackjack-pizzeria-la-habra?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 429,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9398719780954,
        "longitude": -117.973393835127
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "2429 W Whittier Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "La Habra",
        "zip_code": "90631",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "2429 W Whittier Blvd",
          "La Habra, CA 90631"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15626944111",
      "display_phone": "(562) 694-4111",
      "distance": 6649.561538223691
    },
    {
      "id": "lCn-WpZORhjjuVeXiNt5hA",
      "alias": "pizzamania-whittier",
      "name": "Pizzamania",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/oikKRCcC4Kncp0BBlruVYg/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizzamania-whittier?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 1027,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9378271,
        "longitude": -118.0427549
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "13547 Telegraph Rd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90605",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "13547 Telegraph Rd",
          "Whittier, CA 90605"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15629448803",
      "display_phone": "(562) 944-8803",
      "distance": 8691.538482559992
    },
    {
      "id": "4qcbUWK6PtT_EhE1CL00OQ",
      "alias": "ravello-osteria-monterey-park",
      "name": "Ravello Osteria",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/SL-IEVhRUfuFcz1aZzYEQg/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/ravello-osteria-monterey-park?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 578,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "italian",
          "title": "Italian"
        },
        {
          "alias": "pastashops",
          "title": "Pasta Shops"
        },
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.036084111352146,
        "longitude": -118.1307262
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "2315 S Garfield Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Monterey Park",
        "zip_code": "91754",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "2315 S Garfield Ave",
          "Monterey Park, CA 91754"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+13237227600",
      "display_phone": "(323) 722-7600",
      "distance": 14181.449997149568
    },
    {
      "id": "a9Oo2cUQXv4V7sNzlWiMNQ",
      "alias": "pizza-21-whittier",
      "name": "Pizza 21",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/r37IuAf-RTO9YlkTTtHKKQ/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizza-21-whittier?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 220,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9718658905689,
        "longitude": -118.07371439367
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "8017 Norwalk Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": null,
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90606",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "8017 Norwalk Blvd",
          "Whittier, CA 90606"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15628013689",
      "display_phone": "(562) 801-3689",
      "distance": 8853.647033272864
    },
    {
      "id": "LKPl3iThbC2CdbnPb53XRQ",
      "alias": "the-curry-pizza-company-walnut-walnut-2",
      "name": "The Curry Pizza Company - Walnut",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/WaC6AFze5NVW9OrL_uGJ7g/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-curry-pizza-company-walnut-walnut-2?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 318,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "indpak",
          "title": "Indian"
        },
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "chicken_wings",
          "title": "Chicken Wings"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.0111996,
        "longitude": -117.859211
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "376 S Lemon Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": null,
        "city": "Walnut",
        "zip_code": "91789",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "376 S Lemon Ave",
          "Walnut, CA 91789"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+19099785065",
      "display_phone": "(909) 978-5065",
      "distance": 11533.359141110845
    },
    {
      "id": "Wcg_6rnWc6tpktt33ous7Q",
      "alias": "baby-bros-pizza-and-wings-south-el-monte",
      "name": "Baby Bros Pizza & Wings",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/MZ115Qxa5HTZvCGLWxYw5w/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/baby-bros-pizza-and-wings-south-el-monte?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 292,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "chicken_wings",
          "title": "Chicken Wings"
        },
        {
          "alias": "beerbar",
          "title": "Beer Bar"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.05211,
        "longitude": -118.05398
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "9847 Rush St",
        "address2": null,
        "address3": "",
        "city": "South El Monte",
        "zip_code": "91733",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "9847 Rush St",
          "South El Monte, CA 91733"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16264482316",
      "display_phone": "(626) 448-2316",
      "distance": 8772.804450272562
    },
    {
      "id": "2UJcwkqvDAKPX8ZeNbQeFQ",
      "alias": "pizzarev-rowland-heights",
      "name": "PizzaRev",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/PiDjlQH6Nw7u4q9TLhaGQg/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizzarev-rowland-heights?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 397,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9901605,
        "longitude": -117.9246713
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "17490 Colima Rd",
        "address2": "Ste D",
        "address3": null,
        "city": "Rowland Heights",
        "zip_code": "91748",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "17490 Colima Rd",
          "Ste D",
          "Rowland Heights, CA 91748"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16268540006",
      "display_phone": "(626) 854-0006",
      "distance": 5511.128701794727
    },
    {
      "id": "SiyyceCOoIuEqCfZEwN3Hg",
      "alias": "pie-trap-pizza-covina",
      "name": "Pie Trap Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/o8_i3RxRXkFDDRu3p9l08Q/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pie-trap-pizza-covina?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 20,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.105086485939346,
        "longitude": -117.87669418232004
      },
      "transactions": [
        
      ],
      "location": {
        "address1": "720 E Arrow Hwy",
        "address2": "Ste A",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Covina",
        "zip_code": "91702",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "720 E Arrow Hwy",
          "Ste A",
          "Covina, CA 91702"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+16265410051",
      "display_phone": "(626) 541-0051",
      "distance": 15352.567810724982
    },
    {
      "id": "efqeidrFoFzqVH1TEmJHIg",
      "alias": "new-york-pizzeria-walnut",
      "name": "New York Pizzeria",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/36tqlCLWgOLgIaYasL19Qw/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/new-york-pizzeria-walnut?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 246,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "beer_and_wine",
          "title": "Beer, Wine & Spirits"
        },
        {
          "alias": "sandwiches",
          "title": "Sandwiches"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.0190473,
        "longitude": -117.8650573
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "364 N Lemon Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Walnut",
        "zip_code": "91789",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "364 N Lemon Ave",
          "Walnut, CA 91789"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+19095945000",
      "display_phone": "(909) 594-5000",
      "distance": 11138.41781108791
    },
    {
      "id": "nG3lHSvq3m0fzFQTdHjUSw",
      "alias": "tonys-pizza-whittier",
      "name": "Tony's Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/lZ7c-viftcFik1Y06I8xJA/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tonys-pizza-whittier?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 518,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9422540037959,
        "longitude": -117.995184817488
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "15624 Whittwood Ln",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90603",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "15624 Whittwood Ln",
          "Whittier, CA 90603"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15629470500",
      "display_phone": "(562) 947-0500",
      "distance": 6411.01480512212
    },
    {
      "id": "DOB_k_gkyijSLgyt-_zodQ",
      "alias": "jo-peeps-ny-pizza-whittier-3",
      "name": "Jo Peeps Ny Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/vX-ghkTzaweOhKEIvq5wzw/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/jo-peeps-ny-pizza-whittier-3?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 193,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "salad",
          "title": "Salad"
        },
        {
          "alias": "sandwiches",
          "title": "Sandwiches"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.9535433,
        "longitude": -118.0161173
      },
      "transactions": [
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "14450 Whittier Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90605",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "14450 Whittier Blvd",
          "Whittier, CA 90605"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15629459691",
      "display_phone": "(562) 945-9691",
      "distance": 5891.520785405544
    },
    {
      "id": "2z5o4QXHgDc6vQLqZYoI8w",
      "alias": "pizza-n-brews-whittier-3",
      "name": "Pizza-N-Brews",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/eowFStZQxkd0V4bPg5rigA/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizza-n-brews-whittier-3?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 43,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        },
        {
          "alias": "sandwiches",
          "title": "Sandwiches"
        },
        {
          "alias": "beerbar",
          "title": "Beer Bar"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4.5,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.94714,
        "longitude": -118.00047
      },
      "transactions": [
        "pickup",
        "delivery"
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "15309 Whittier Blvd",
        "address2": null,
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Whittier",
        "zip_code": "90603",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "15309 Whittier Blvd",
          "Whittier, CA 90603"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+15629056048",
      "display_phone": "(562) 905-6048",
      "distance": 5980.620672175974
    },
    {
      "id": "TK-qu1WwApLzzhRvKn7Mfg",
      "alias": "tonys-little-italy-pizza-placentia",
      "name": "Tony's Little Italy Pizza",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/tF4DOUTxrpPSSOvJW3P1ZA/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tonys-little-italy-pizza-placentia?adjust_creative=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=WpoQHLnOMdOyEndsLlwSPg",
      "review_count": 2170,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "pizza",
          "title": "Pizza"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 33.8955049585903,
        "longitude": -117.872027337872
      },
      "transactions": [
        
      ],
      "price": "$$",
      "location": {
        "address1": "1808 N Placentia Ave",
        "address2": "Unit B",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Placentia",
        "zip_code": "92870",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "CA",
        "display_address": [
          "1808 N Placentia Ave",
          "Unit B",
          "Placentia, CA 92870"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+17145282159",
      "display_phone": "(714) 528-2159",
      "distance": 15438.106560936967
    }
  ],
  "total": 1700,
  "region": {
    "center": {
      "longitude": -117.9834738,
      "latitude": 33.9990858
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a SwiftUI issue, you are missing the initial values for everything, if you type `Result(` you will see all the variables that are required in the suggestions. You can also just make it optional `@Published var result: Result?`

Comment: @loremipsum I am missing (businesses:region:) as I typed `Result(`. Making result: Result? seems to work. But in my view, I still can't get anything after the `result?.businesses.` How do I get those values?

Comment: @Published properties can be optional and that would be a very good choice for something you fetch asynchronous like `Result`

Comment: I can access the values by adding `[0]` to the end of the `result?.businesses` as `result?.businesses[0]` since this is an array. I can finally continue on my project. Thanks StackOverFlow